# Trocar textos por imagens

Tags: jquery, html

Boa noite, Como posso alterar os textos ( Background 1, Background 2, Background 3 ) por imagens?

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ntpdy2a5/)

Obrigado!!

Comment: Explique melhor. Não deu pra entender o que vc quer?

Comment: Tipo, em vez das palavras Background 1, 2, 3, eu queria que fosse 3 imagens, tem como?

Comment: Claro. Substitua as palavras por `<img src="caminho_da_imagem" />`.

Comment: Desculpe, sou muito noob nisso, encontrei o código na internet mas não sei como fazer, poderia me mostrar como faz? Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Voce parece bem iniciante , recomendo muito esse curso, caso nao conheca ainda https://www.cursoemvideo.com/course/curso-de-html5/

Comment: Não conhecia, vou dar uma olhada depois, obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja o Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntpdy2a5/3/

Substituí os textos por imagens e coloquei um `alt` em cada imagem com o texto que tinha antes.

Comment: Era isso msm que eu queria, muito obrigado David. :)

Comment: Marca a resposta como respondida.